# Android Studio generating correct app-debug.apk file but showing old version of code

Tags: android, reactjs, android-studio, capacitor

I have an app that is build using React and is wrapped in capacitor. I was having no issues running the app in debug mode on android studio a month ago, or creating release files, but now I am.

I have checked the app-debug.apk (static/js/main.chunk......) file that is created when I select run, and it contains the updated code, I have sent the package to a colleague who ran the .apk on their machine and saw the updated code, but on my emulator and on my android devices, I am seeing an old version of the code.

I have removed all debug-release.apk files on my Mac and followed steps online such as clean build/rebuild, updates off mac, android studio etc but still no luck.

I am at a complete loss now.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update: After much troubleshooting, we deleted the build folder android>app>build and the rebuilt the app, and ran it, and it fixed the issue.